# How could making a soul more demonically compatible lead to a reversal in demonic possession?

Tags: magic, demons

Daemonhosts are created when daemonic spirits are bound to the flesh of human beings, allowing them to hijack the individual's soul and giving them control over the victim. Within this union, the daemon acts like software, using the body like a puppet, and the individual is the hardware being made to perform actions. The problem is that the software's output can only be as good as the hardware's capability. This is similar to installing Windows 10 on an old system running XP: It would barely work, suffering numerous problems and returning lackluster performance. The soul of an adult human is structurally solid and no longer as malleable, and eventually leads to an obsolescence where the body decays and disintegrates from the daemonic aura poring from them. The only solution to this problem is to build a human body from scratch that is specifically designed to contain a daemon's power.

The Nazi project known as Lebensborn was a state sopported association in Germany created by HYDRA, an occultist subgroup under the Schutzstaffel, with the stated goal of producing future proud members of the Aryan race. White, blond-haired and blue-eyed, These children would be tomorrow's leaders of the glorious Third Reich as true manifestations of Hitler's master race. In truth however, these children were meant to serve as perfect subjects for daemonic possession. A specific daemon would implant a portion of his aura into the developing soul of the child. This energy would manipulate the soul while it is more malleable and less structured, making it perfectly compatible to suit the daemon. This would allow for a perfect daemonhost that the spirit could permanently inhabit without fear. When the child grows into a young adult, the possession ritual would take place in which the daemon would bond with the host to take control.   "Heil, mein Führer!

However, the Nazi's master race of a super soldier army of daemons backfired in a mysterious way. It was discovered that these possessions left the daemon subject to the individual! The daemon was now a slave to the human that it inhabited, allowing the possessed to use the daemon's power as it was his own and denying the spirit the control that it wanted. Ironically, making a soul compatible with a daemon will ultimately reverse the traditional system of control, as opposed to an incompatible victim. These spoiled brats, thinking themselves above their masters, have refused to swear their allegiance to the great Fuhrer and have risen up to take power for themselves, putting the future of the Reich into question!

How could a Nazi program to create demonically possessed children go horribly awry?

Comment: Reading the question only, my initial response was "You mean aside from the obvious?"  Might need to fine tune the title question.

Comment: @hszmv: exactly! I was thinking: "How could this ***not*** go awry?"

Comment: Go awry?  It starts out being awry.

Comment: I don't think the title matches the actual question. The title asks for a scenario, but the scenario is readily prepared in the opening. The nazi's did not need deamons to control kids. Nor did heavily indoctrinated nazi kids ever form a resistance of any kind.

Answer (score 3):

By giving a developing human a piece of the daemon's own aura, the human learns and develops around it.  This includes learning how to control that aura lest it poison and kill the child.

This actually had two effects -- one planned and one unplanned.  The planned effect was that this daemontouched child was a far more compatible host for that particular daemon.  This was the plan, and it was probably meticulously thought out without regard for the human will or condition.

The unforeseen effect, the one that damns the daemon, is that it makes the human very good at controlling the daemon's aura as they have been since before their birth.  By the time the very suitable vessel is ready for possession, it is also quite capable of controlling more aura than was implanted into the child.  Also, this is the child's body, giving the human yet another advantage when the daemon tries to take over.

In this case, it was less making the soul more compatible that doomed the attempt, but the method that it was done in.  It was basically like inoculating children against daemonic possession as so when they were possessed, they could fight it and win.

Answer (score 2):

> How can making a soul demonically-compatible reverse the order of a spirit possession?

They used the wrong texts and did not study thoroughly their Catechism. The "corruption of the soul" is a metaphor; a human soul is in itself incorruptible, and can only be stained by *sin*.

It has nothing to do with *compatibility*. It has to do with *will*. The normal possession process has the demon corrupt the will of the victim, by leveraging their extant fall from grace, through successive temptations through which the victim's will aligns more and more with the demon's intentions, and sins more and more, until the barrier to actual, physical possession goes down and the human can be thoroughly possessed - perhaps a more apt term would be "mind-wiped".

By the way, in any moment before the last stage the victim may realize their situation, repent sincerely and find themselves back in the grace of God, thereby rejecting possession altogether. The soul is never "repaired", it is "cleansed".

The ritual naively bypassed the whole "wearing down of the host's will", artificially lowering the barrier from the outside. The result is, as planned, the demon's power being at the disposal of the host... but the host's will is still their own.

So, their indoctrination - their belief that the superior man must always dominate the *untermensch* - plus the natural arrogance engendered by demonic possession turns the young Demonlords in independent, dangerous little world dominators bent on grabbing power for themselves, and the devil take the hindmost.

Possibly, their controllers hoped the children would feel *loyalty* to the Reich, *love* for the Fuhrer, have *faith* in the Party, put its needs above their own.

But they overlooked the simple truth that *loyalty*, *honesty*, *love*, *faith*, *selflessness* are all **virtues**.

Answer (score 1):

The way, they thought, to make the host more suitable was to make it stronger.  Unfortunately for them, this meant it was stronger at fighting for control.

Furthermore, the less structured nature of the soul meant it was harder for the daemonic forces to gain a permanent foothold.  This resulted in a war over the childhood of the host, strengthening the child day by day so that as structure was added, it used against the daemonic forces, rather than giving them a further foothold.

When the daemon itself came, it found itself trapped inside a strong soul further strengthened by an endless struggle. It didn't have a chance.

Answer (score 1):

## The Daemon Seed Grew:

So you put a little bit of the demon in the child, a PERFECT child for a daemon to live in. But it is a itty, bitty bit of demon - like a seed. Normal humans are lousy places for daemon spirits to grow. But into this wonderful soil, the mustard seed has grown into a huge bush.

In truth, the children are ALL READY DAEMONS. The human soul has been essentially displaced by the little nugget which has blossomed into adulthood. But these daemons are indistinguishable from humans, since they grew up just like human children. Of course, they grew up to be flint - cold, ruthless, and as hard as Krupp steel. Who could tell the difference?

So a daemon arrives and tries to overwrite a human, but instead they have to contend with a fully functional daemon already well entrenched. A daemon who didn't grow up in Thule, but here in the mortal realm. A daemon who doesn't give a crap about ancient feuds and causes.

One willing to deal with the enemy to get what they want, or possibly even arrogant enough to believe that a liberal free-market democracy will guarantee that a clever, resourceful being will inevitably dominate the lesser folk - you know, good businessmen and politicians.

Answer (score 0):

### They made nephilim.

It turns out, like with pregnant angels, when you implant a demon soul into a human you create an angel human hybrid. They are extremely compatible with possession, but dormant connections of the human brain have been awoken, and the humans have the true power that comes from being made in the image of god.

They have a direct tap to a higher plane of energy, which some might call heaven, and which demons would call a blinding burning light that tears and rends, allowing them to empower their souls to overcome any demonic possession.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking of it like magnetism. For the demon soul to stop the human soul from having control of the body it needs to bind to the matching (possibly weak, but possibly just human) parts of a human soul. However merging the human soul with a demonic part the weakness or softness allowing a full bind is long gone when the actual demon tries to bind to the human, not giving it any space to get into the human's mind.

Also maybe humans usually have that property of clinging very tightly to the demonic part that possesses them, which usually works against them, since their own will is paralyzed exept for the inability of ever letting a demon go. But if having a bit of a demonic soul makes them immune to the paralyzing control taking part of the demon, but doesn't hinder their ability to cling to the demon very very tightly, so there is no way the demon is ever getting rid of that fully functioning and agile human soul again.

Answer (score 0):

Your Nazi occultists made the mistake of not accounting for the will of the demons.

It turns out that demons enjoy wearing down adult host bodies until they disintegrate. Like with human sexual predators, it's all about the thrill of the chase, or breaking down resistance. However, now that the occultists have provided pliable kids for them, they have essentially spoiled the demons' fun. On the other hand, the daemonhost program has unknowingly been creating/selecting for psychopathic behaviour in children under the guise of political indoctrination. The kids have also noticed that Hitler himself, and many of his top officials are not blond haired and blue eyed, and therefore they must themselves be *untermensch*.

Noticing the change in circumstances, the demons struck a private arrangement with the little monsters unbeknownst to the HYDRA sorcerers. Scheming demons and willing hosts form a new symbiosis completely outside of Nazi control. This new breed now apply their abilities to tearing down the Nazi state apparatus in the most violent way possible, so that the demons can savour the delightful torment of the entire German nation

Of course, the demons intend on destroying the children once they grow up in the same way as the prior adult hosts, but that's a problem for another day...

Answer (score 0):

**They are so susceptible to possession that multiple demons are fighting over the body at any one time**

This leaves the human will free to control the body, and a portion of each demon's power, as the demons are chaotic and incapable of working together.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out posession is always a two-way-swap. The demon posesses the man, the man posesses the demon.
An adult finds this experience traumatic, as they lose their connection to the physical world and can't make sense of the demon realm. Demons don't really care about this because human souls temporarily in the demon realm tend to sit in a corner sobbing. Similarly, a normal humans response is to desire to return to their own body, so continued posession of an adult takes a lot of energy - the demon has to override the humans will.

In order to be more 'possessable' people, they have to be more comfortable in the demon realm. A person who is happy to swap places with a demon can be posessed just by asking. "Want to swap places for a bit?" "Yeah sure." So any training to increase possesibility inherently requires that human more familiar with the demon realm. The younger you start them, the better they adapt. The end result leaves a demon posessing a body in the human realm, and a fully aware and alert human soul in the demon realm.

So what can a human do in the demon realm? Well, turns out all those demonic powers aren't an 'individual demon thing' - they're tied to the interaction between realms. Any entity in the demon realm with some connection to the human realm can draw energy from one to the other. A human has the ultimate connection to the human realm, so can wield a good deal of power. As such the possesion switches from a demon-in-charge-possession to a symbiotic relationship: from both sides it is: "If you possess me I can give you access to lots of power."

So why did the Nazi's do this: It promised super soldiers! The demons said it would make them more powerful, and it did
Why did it go wrong?

Just as demon possession can corrupt a human soul and make it nastier and less caring .... a human soul can corrupt a demon's, introducing concepts like empathy and love. As such any sufficiently bonded human-demon pair is chaotic-neutral: capable of great good and great evil, swinging from one to the other unpredictably. They may refuse to take part in a large scale invasion (and how could you force them), and then spend the next week playing with plate tectonics to try create a new volcano - causing thousands of deaths. They are children, after all.